# photonServiceSettings missing from Unity and can't use photon lib

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

> Could not load PhotonServerSettings to update RPCs.
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   Photon.Pun.PhotonEditor:UpdateRpcList() (at
>   Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/Editor/PhotonEditor.cs:661)
>   Photon.Pun.PhotonEditor:OnInitialHierarchyChanged() (at
>   Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/Editor/PhotonEditor.cs:198)
>   UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallHierarchyHasChanged()

photonServiceSettings file is missing from photon lib.. although I have a bunch of files related.. this is why I got the error.

Tried to integrate the unique ID from https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/Photon into my unity project.
Tried to install/reinstall photon (last version September 2019) with no success, cannot advance my multiplayer project because of this.

Could not load PhotonServerSettings to update RPCs.

Answer (score 4):

My solve was to create a folder called "Resources" inside "Assets\Photon\PhotonUnityNetworking"

As I did this the setup project window re-appeared and everything continued as expected.
This is on a project that has been running for a number of years and just converted from PUN+ to PUN2

Answer (score 0):

Find and copy from anywhere a file `PhotonServerSettings.asset` and put in this directory of your project:

```
Assets\Photon\PhotonUnityNetworking\Resources
```

Then assign AAppID from the dashboard on Photon's website.
You can try to download my file from GD
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12fqPvPcxZiR9cmonPgwLFsyS0DACDAPV

Comment: did this already, but there were some issues out there, I will post a comment how did I solved that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
If you create a new project in which you include PUN setup, i.e.: ID, personal info for project, then you will have a bunch of directories containing some basic files. I moved (copied) those directories to my trouble project and it worked. "photonServerSettings" file was there as well if I remember well.